# print_r($response) shows data but can't be accessed

Tags: php, arrays, facebook-graph-api

I'm requesting an access token from Facebook and the new response (since API v2.3) looks like this after using `print_r($response);`:

PHP:

```
Array ( [{"access_token":"123","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":111}]
```

I tried `$response[0]->access_token` and `$response['access_token']` and both are returning nothing.
How to get the access_token value?

Comment: Can you do `var_dump($response);` and show us the output?

Comment: The Output of var_dump: `array(1) { ["{"access_token":"123","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":111}"]=> string(0) "" } `

Comment: use `json_decode($response)` to convert it to `array`

Comment: @Faradox That is incorrect on two accounts: without the 2nd parameter as `false` `json_decode` will output objects, not arrays. Secondly `$response` is an array, not a string so decoding will fail.

Answer (score -1):

I think `$response` looks like:

```
$response = array(
    '{"access_token":"123","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":111}' => ""
);
```

Somehow you've set the JSON body of the response as the key.

You can still access the token but it's a bit weird:

```
$json_response = key($response);
$data = json_decode($json_response, false);
$token = $data["access_token"]; // "123"
```

Comment: It's not working - is it possible that the response is a sting instead of an array? How to test or convert it?

Comment: `key($response)` should give you the json string.

Comment: Can you do some debugging? I can't help you much since I don't have access to your full script. Also, figure out why `$response` is such a weird value.